# Mapstruct : Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two methods for mapping entity to domain.

```
RDomain entityToDomain(REntity rEntity)

/*
this method ignores some of the fields in the domain.
*/
RDomain entityToDomainLight(REntity rEntity)
```

I'm getting **Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection** element when I try to define mapping method for List of entities to domains.

```
List<RDomain> entitiesToDomains(List<REntity> rEntities)
```

Is there a way to define which method to use for mapping collection of objects

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As @Filip suggested, it is better to do something like that :

```
RDomain entityToDomain(REntity rEntity)

@Named(value = "useMe")
RDomain entityToDomainLight(REntity rEntity)

@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "useMe")
List<RDomain> entitiesToDomains(List<REntity> rEntities)
```

Comment: Solved by `@Named(value = "useMe")`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Mapstruct, there is no wo to tell a mapper

```
List<RDomain> entitiesToDomains(List<REntity> rEntities)
```

which of your to mapping methods it should use. But you can implement `entitiesToDomains` as a Java 8 default method on your mapper interface.

```
default List<RDomain> entitiesToDomains(List<REntity> rEntities) {

    List<RDomain> domains = new ArrayList<>();

    for(REntity r : rEntities) {
       //delegate to your dedicated mapper
       domains.add(entityToDomainLight(r));
    }

    return domains;

}
```

Comment: You can actually achieve that by using [`IterableMapping#qualifiedByName`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/IterableMapping.html#qualifiedByName--) or [`IterableMapping#quelifiedBy`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/IterableMapping.html#qualifiedBy--). It is in the documentation, but not that exposed :)

Comment: Cool. I did not know that. Going to update by answer

Comment: Of course you would need to put a qualifier (MapStruct one) on the entity mapper methods